# Restructering Dataframes (stored in dictionairy)

Tags: pandas, dictionary

i have footballdata stored in a dictionairy by league for different seasons. So for example I have the results from 1 league for the seasons 2017-2020 in one dataframe stored in the dictionary. Now I need to create new dataframes by season, so that I have all the results from 2019 in one dataframe. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You should provide us some sample of your data and write what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

- assuming you are using [open football](https://github.com/openfootball/football.json) as your source
- use GitHub API to get all files in repo
- function to normalize the JSON
- simple to generate either a concatenated DF of a **dict** of all the results

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# normalize footbal scores data into a dataframe
def structuredf(res):
    js = res.json()

    if "rounds" not in res.json().keys():
        return (pd.json_normalize(js["matches"])
                .pipe(lambda d: d.loc[:,].join(d["score.ft"].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:"home",1:"away"})))
                .drop(columns="score.ft")
                .rename(columns={"round":"name"})
                .assign(seasonname=js["name"], url=res.url)
               )
    df = (pd.json_normalize(pd.json_normalize(js["rounds"])
                            .explode("matches").to_dict("records"))
          .assign(seasonname=js["name"], url=res.url)
          .pipe(lambda d: d.loc[:,].join(d["matches.score.ft"].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:"home",1:"away"})))
          .drop(columns="matches.score.ft")
          .pipe(lambda d: d.rename(columns={c:c.split(".")[-1] for c in d.columns}))
         )
    return df

# get listing of all datafiles that we're interested in
res = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/openfootball/football.json/git/trees/master?recursive=1")
dfm = pd.DataFrame(res.json()["tree"])

# concat into one dataframe
df = pd.concat([structuredf(res) 
                for p in dfm.loc[dfm["path"].str.contains(r".en.[0-9]+.json"), "path"].iteritems()
               for res in [requests.get(f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/{p[1]}")]])

# dictionary of dataframe
d = {res.json()["name"]:structuredf(res) 
                for p in dfm.loc[dfm["path"].str.contains(r".en.[0-9]+.json"), "path"].iteritems()
               for res in [requests.get(f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/{p[1]}")]}
```